# How to run root in autostart

Tags: python-3, lxde

I have successfully launched a python script using "LXDE-PI" autostart function, however, this script needs to run as root in order to function correctly. How can I do this? Where would I need to add sudo?

Answer (score 0):

In your LXDE-pi autostart file:

Add `sudo` in front of your Python script call:
`@/usr/bin/python /your/python/script.py` -> `@sudo /usr/bin/python /your/python/script.py`